# Can't pin Desktop icon to dock favorites in Pop!_OS

Tags: pop-os, dock

I'm using `Pop!_OS 22.04`.

I just downloaded and installed a new app (PyCharm), but it didn't come with an icon for my dock. I created a new icon using this `~/.local/share/applications/pycharm.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/opt/pycharm-2022.1.1/bin/pycharm.sh
Name=PyCharm
Icon=/home/USERNAME/Pictures/icons/pycharm.png
```

This seems to work great. I can see the icon I chose when I look for the app, and it opens in my dock. The only problem is that I can't seem to pin it to my dock's favorites.

The "Add to Favorites" button that every other dock icon has when I right click on them doesn't appear in my new icon at all.

Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something? Is this a bug?

Update: I've seen this on other apps too, but for PyCharm, turns out there's an option in the GUI to create the desktop launcher. It appears to do exactly the same thing I did (place a `.desktop` file in the same folder), but it also adds a few extra keys. The biggest one seems to be `StartupWMClass`. If that key is included, the "Add to Favorites" option appears when you right-click the icon in the dock. If the `StartupWMClass` key is not present, the "Add to Favorites" option is not there.

Why is that? What does that option do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to your problem:

1. Add line `StartupNotify=true` to your `~/.local/share/applications/pycharm.desktop` file
2. Restart GNOME (Alt + F2) + run command: "`r`" or with shell command `killall -3 gnome-shell` (**This is very important step**)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with **GitKraken**:

[image]

**Workaround:**
Open ***Applications menu***, search for the app you want to add to Favourites and **Pin to Dash**

[image]

Done:

[image]